# IPC not found with cygwin

Tags: c, linux, cygwin

I have a problem that I can't create message queue with cygwin:

```
if ((queue_ID = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE,IPC_CREAT|0666)) < 0)
    {
        printf("msgget\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

This code just returns "msgget" string. Why not, what's wrong? How can I install message queues with cygwin?

Comment: How is cyg**win** related to Linux?

Comment: So how can I use IPC without installing linux?

Comment: How is cygwin or IPC related to C?

Comment: I just googled "IPC in Windows" and it linked me to [an MSDN page entitled "Interprocess Communications"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx). Have you read that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem like any research was attempted prior to asking this question

Comment: Not sure if you can. But That was not my question.

Comment: [Cygserver](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygserver.html) must be run.